# How can I strip any and all HTML tags from a string?

Tags: c#, html

I have a string defined like so:

```
private const String REFER_TO_BUSINESS = "<pre> (Refer to business office for guidance and explain below the circumstances for exception to policy or attach a copy of request)</pre>";
```

...which has, as you can see, the "pre" tag to preserve the space prepended to the verbiage. I want to, though, reference this string without the "pre" tags. It would be easy enough to search for "<pre>" and "</pre>" and remove them, but it would quickly become tedious to do that with every HTML tag type.

How can I, in C#, strip all tags out of a string, regardless of whether they are "<pre>", "<h1>", "<span>", "<aside>" or anything else?

Comment: Here's the trouble with the regex implementations in the answers so far - they clobber strings like `x < 6 && y > 8`, which doesn't contain any HTML tags.

Comment: Good point, but doesn't apply to my use case.

Comment: @jdphenix Maybe it is because to be a valid html your string should be as `x &lt; 6 &amp;&amp; y &gt; 8`

Comment: @EZI I never asserted my sample string was HTML.

Comment: @jdphenix so it can not exist in an html tag. Then no problem with below regexes

Comment: @jdphenix BTW: I don't say parsing an html with regex is a good idea (I guess everyone here have already read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/932418)). But your sample is not correct. Find a better case.

Comment: @EZI It may be true that the string I supplied isn't valid HTML, but most browsers would be able to handle the incorrectness and display as you may expect regardless. My only point was that they will remove anything between angle brackets - irrespective of if it is valid HTML. Bugs are all about unexpected cases.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon `Good point, but doesn't apply to my use case.` If your case is always as simple as in your question, then you can use it, but it is not the correct way to get the text between html tags. Use an Html parser like HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: @EZI Ok - you've got me there. There is not a test case in that it is valid HTML and the regex solution wouldn't work. It's just... smelly. :)

Comment: What's wrong with HtmlAgilityPack and calling Text method on the result of parsing the string as shown in search results for title of your post - https://www.bing.com/search?q=How+can+I+strip+any+and+all+HTML+tags+from+a+string%3F ? (Looks like duplicate to me so far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a regex replacement.
This pattern matches html tags within a string. From [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx/)

```
        var pattern = @"</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^'"">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>";
        var source = "<pre> (Refer to business office for guidance and explain below the circumstances for exception to policy or attach a copy of request)</pre>";
        Regex.Replace(source, pattern, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need it to do:

```
 string stripMeOfHTML = Regex.Replace(stripMeOfHTML, @"<[^>]+>", "").Trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
// For strings that have embedded HTML tags for presentation on the form (such as "<pre>" and such), but need to be rendered free of these (such as on the PDF)
private String RemoveHTMLTags(String stringContainingHTMLTags)
{
    String regexified = Regex.Replace(stringContainingHTMLTags, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
    return regexified;
}
```